# Thread pooling - notify main a job succeeded, and exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I'm trying to implement a thread pool, where each worker tries to solve a puzzle (different paths down a decision tree).
The thing is that i want the if one of the workers found a solution, it will notify the main thread, saying "this is the solution", and make all the threads exit
currently I'm just **busy waiting** in the main thread for the return of future of the threads
can i somehow notify the main thread while it still runs? I have in mind something like interrupts, or a callback function that the solver thread can call and kill all the other threads from within.

Comment: You could have all the threads periodically (and atomically) check a completion flag?

Comment: Perhaps [*condition variables*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread#Condition_variables)?

Comment: What do you mean while the main thread still runs? What is that thread supposed to be doing? If you want it to be notified, you have to either put it in a waiting state using WaitForMultipleObjects for instance or manually poll some events periodically.

Comment: in your thread function i guess you have some kind of loop, so have it check a condition_variable, once one thread finds the solution do a notify_all on the condition_variable to stop the threads. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable